# php openssl_encrypt - always getting some strange output when idle

Tags: php, function, openssl, output, encode

Having a trouble with openssl_encrypt function. I made encoder/decoder what takes input from one form and place output into another. With folowing code everything works BUT I'm getting always some output in the beginning even when no parameters are in forms/variables. When I fill forms, evertything works perfect. I made reseach and spend whole evening on this but nothing so far... (...atleast I learned other PHP things:)

```
<?php
$encode = $_POST["encode"];
$saltE = $_POST["keyE"];
$ivE = $_POST["ivE"];

$encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";

if ($encode === "" && $saltE === "") {
  $warningE = "You forgot to enter text";
} elseif (!($encode === "") && !($saltE === "") && !($ivE === "")) {
  $encoded = openssl_encrypt($encode, $encrypt_method, $saltE, 0, $ivE);
} elseif (!($encode === "") && ($saltE === "")) {
  $warningEE = 'Key parameter is missing';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
var_dump( $_POST );
```

to see what's happening.

I suspect you have code like this:

```
<textarea>
</textarea>
```

when it should be like this (no spaces):

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: it returns string(24) "H3iP5thsMXVJaX+/DAf6Qw==" , so the same crypted (unknown) as I see in <textarea>. I'm curious what this code crypting, when there is no input :/

Comment: What do you get if you put 
"var_dump( $_POST );
exit;"   on the top of file?

Comment: I've got "array(0) { } "

Comment: Uh, please put  "var_dump( $_POST ); exit;" before "$encoded = openssl_encrypt....."

Comment: I tryed and I've got the same result now "array(0) { } ", it should contain some data ? When I loaded the script, I see only this result on screen, nothing else.

Comment: Yes, you should get something like { "encode" : '' ... } 
you can try and put "if( !empty( $_POST ) ){ var_dump( $_POST ); exit; }" anywhere